# How can I log all HTTP requests to rails app in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to be able to log all http requests to a rails app, even those to static assets in the public folder. I'd like to do this with a standard rails setup, e.g. using ./script/server, and without installing Apache, etc.

I tried wireshark, but it seems like it doesn't track local traffic. I also tried to use the request object, but that only knows about the request url, not the subsequent css+image+js assets.

I'm using Rails 2.3.4 on Mac OS 10.5. By the way, Yslow, etc. won't work for my setup (android development).

Answer (score 1):

${RAILS_ROOT}/log/development.log is not enoug?